# Enumeration PHP Email form request

Tags: php, forms, web

I have a PHP web form that sends an email to a user with a work request.  The user would like the requests to be numbered in sequence, almost like a ticket number. (example 1, 2, 3) (I am guessing the user did not anticipate the volume of requests and they became hard to keep track of.)  I am not sure how to set this up, as the requests do not go into a database. How do I incrementally increase the number associated with emails that are sent out?

Comment: and your code consists of?

Comment: Actually the question is quite clear.

Comment: heh...yeah quite ^ edit: I meant "unclear". as in their question. Misread that.

Comment: You need some sort of persistent storage, no way around that. If you cannot use a database, then maybe you can at least use a simple file for a counter, but that means very bad performance compared to a database. Maybe you could simply ask that user to sort the requests by date? Or add the date to the subject?

Comment: I was thinking of creating a simple text file, with the request number written to it.  But I am not very familiar on how to read the entry from the text.  Then it would be a simple +1 and write back to the text.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry for not being very clear, I am looking for a 7 mile out view on how to get this accomplished  that is why I asked for suggestions.  My apologies

Comment: It is difficult to associate a monotonically increasing number unless you have some authority source that is persisted (such as a database). Do you have any such source that can be integrated, even if it is just a file on the server?

Comment: If available, I'd give [sqlite3](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php) a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a hard requirement that you use a monotonically increasing number (versus, say, a date) you will need to have some *authority source* that has certain constraints:

- It is persistent. If a server goes down, that source will still be there when the server comes back up.
- It is available. If multiple servers need access to the source, they have some way of getting to it.

A database serves this purpose for most people in most cases. At the point when multiple servers are needed, you can move the database to it's own server and make it available to the web application serving servers.

If you only have one server you can use a file, as [described here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp). The file would hold the number, and you'd need to overwrite it with a new number every time you send an email. Note that if multiple processes try to write to the same file, you may run into a locking issue (where some processes are trying to open it and have to wait until previous processes are done). Databases are optimized to get around this sort of problem efficiently.

I would recommend that whatever you do you first write a function `get_and_update_number()` (or something equivalent) that returns the number for the email you're sending right then, and also does the side-effect work of persisting that number however it chooses to do it. That way you abstract *how* you do it from the parts of code that need it.